# Query with union() and with() using relation in Model's

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to query Eloquent with union(), but using Model's method on a with().

How do I select these fields correctly?

```
$queryBuilder1 = OneModel::select('column1', 'column2', 'columnForRelationTwoModel')
                   ->select('pkForRelationNextWith')
                   ->with(['relationTwoModelInOneModel' => function($builder]{
                       $builder->select('column3')
                          ->select('pkForRelationNextWith')
                          ->with(
                              ['relationTreeModelInTwoModel' => function($builder){
                                  $builder
                                  ->select('pkForRelationNextWith')
                                  ->with(['relationFourModelInTreeModel' => function($builder) {
                                       $builder->select('column4');
                                   }]);
                               }
                              ]
                          );
                    });

$queryBuilder2 = ModelX::select(
                    'column1_X',
                    DB::raw("'A' as column2"),
                    'column3_X',
                    'column4_x'
                 )
                 ->groupBy('column1_X');

$queryUnion = $queryBuilder1->union($queryBuilder2)->orderBy('column1')->orderBy('column3')->get();
```

My Result:

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT
>   statements have a different number of columns [...]

I expect the output of the 4 united parameters.

Comment: `with` returns the relations as child objects, so you're not getting what you think you are. You probably want to use `join` instead of `with`

Comment: `with` does not return the fields directly from the query builder, but runs additional queries to load relations.

Comment: Gentlemen, I know. The idea is not to use join, but to query with with().

Comment: I updated the question, now the relations are correct, but without progress for the union. :/

Comment: @JhowRaul can you post what result you get when you do `dd([$queryBuilder1->toSql(), $queryBuilder2->toSql()])`

Comment: @NeelBhanushali toSql () does not work in this case as it is doing more than one query to reach the final result. I checked with `DB::enableQueryLog();` and `dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: Another problem is `orderBy ('colum3')`, it does not work for `$queryBuilder1` when inside with.

Comment: You cannot use orderBy with nested columns because those columns do not exist in the context `orderBy` runs. (SQL Query). When using `with()`, Eloquent does other queries, and then appends the result to the resulting collection from the parent model. Therefore, if you want to sort your collection, you have to use `sortBy` (Collection method)

Comment: @JhowRaul I suppose, you are supposed to have similar columns in both select statements so as to union them.

Comment: @IGP Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @NeelBhanushali Yes, my problem is just this: How to create two queries with similar columns using with?